# Background sharing in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, imageview, sharing

Good day, I have some problem with my GridView.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;


    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }


    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    if(LevelActivity.comp[position] == 1)
    { 
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_got);
        Bitmap btm;
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        btm = drawable.getBitmap();
        btm = convertColorIntoBlackAndWhiteImage(btm);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(btm); 
    }

    return imageView;
}
```

Here's code of my ImageAdapter, which set images in GridView. And if position of element is same to position in array with value of 1, it sets b&w image with special background instead of normal image. Everything works fine, BUT:
when I scroll my GridView, that special b&w images starts to "share" their backgrounds to images on their right. So after scrolling I get normal image with special background beside every special b&w element.

Hope you got an idea, thanks.

Image with problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbtwg.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've got an answer. It is really similar to random-items-in-GridView problem. So all I've need to do is set background bitmap directly on canvas (inside b&w function).